# Is there any syscall to trap ctrl+v or shift+insert in golang?

Tags: go

I want to read the clipboard data and paste it in the buffer/ scanf so that I can read the data parse accordingly. My application is entirely written in go as a CLI app.

I used the https://github.com/atotto/clipboard to read the data from the clipboard but now I want this function to be invoked only when the user triggers CRTL+V or SHIFT+INSERT.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/atotto/clipboard"
)

func main() {
    // I want this module to be invoked only when user clicks CTRL+V or SHIFT+INSERT
    text, err := clipboard.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(text)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go for keyboard event processing.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/atotto/clipboard"
    termbox "github.com/nsf/termbox-go"
)

func main() {
    err := termbox.Init()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer termbox.Close()

    // clear
    termbox.Flush()

loop:
    for {
        switch ev := termbox.PollEvent(); ev.Type {
        case termbox.EventKey:
            // program exit
            if ev.Key == termbox.KeyCtrlX {
                break loop
            }
            // past clipboard
            if ev.Key == termbox.KeyCtrlV {
                text, err := clipboard.ReadAll()
                if err == nil {
                    fmt.Println(text)
                }
            }
            termbox.Flush()
        case termbox.EventError:
            panic(ev.Err)
        }
    }
}
```